# Loading controller css in not working in ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Is anyone know how to give css of loading controller in ionic 4? I have tried all the solution which is availbale online but none of its working,so please help me.

I have made one service called loadingService for loading controller then i give css in gloabal.scss or variable.scss is still not working.here is my code.

**loadingService.ts**

```
     async present() {
        this.isLoading = true;
        return await this.loadingController.create({
          spinner: "lines-small",
          duration: 10000,
          cssClass:'loader',

        }).then(a => {
          a.present().then(() => {
            console.log('presented');
            if (!this.isLoading) {
              a.dismiss().then(() => console.log('abort presenting'));
            }
          });
        });
      }

    async dismiss() {
        this.isLoading = false;
        return await this.loadingController.dismiss().then(() => console.log('dismissed'));
      }
```

**gloabal.scss**

```
    .loader {
        --background: #600001;
        --spinner-color: yellow;
      }
```

Please help me on it, and yes i am using ionic 4 so please give me ionic 4 solution not ionic 3.

Comment: try this `.loader {
        --background: #600001 !important;
        --spinner-color: yellow !importat;
      }`

Comment: I have tried this but it's not working.

Comment: what is not working here for you

Comment: css not working for me  after putting this css in global.scss it gives default "PRIMARY" color only.

Comment: surprisingly, if i put your solution in  global.scss it not working but when i shift it in variable.scss it works like a charm, so thanks a ton  @Mohan Gopi

Comment: @AniruddhThakor check the following article https://petercoding.com/2019/04/25/theming-your-app-in-ionic4/#css-custom-properties

Comment: How to increase spinner width?